# How to delete remote repository on github?

Tags: github, repository

I want to know how to delete repo in github account. I cannot see any indicators to delete on github interface.

Comment: See here: https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can go to the main page of the repository and under your repository name, click "Settings"...

[image: Repo Settings tab]

...and scroll down to the "Danger Zone"

[image: The Danger Zone]

Comment: everything is there except for settings!

Comment: @thang I just added the new GitHub UI tabs. Check it out now!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973877/can-not-delete-an-github-repository suggests it's not possible

Answer (score 2):

Go to the settings page of your repo and the bottom you can find the "**Delete this repository**" button under the **Danger Zone** area. Enter your repository name to confirm the deletion and click "**I understand the consequences, delete this repository**" to confirm the operation. The url will endup like below if you visit the settings page of you repository,

```
https://github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/settings
```

For example, if your name is john and have a repository named "sample_john" the url would look like this,

```
https://github.com/john/sample_john/settings
```

***Warning***: Doing the above operation will permanently delete your repository, wiki, issues, and comments, and remove all collaborator associations.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to delete repo from your `.git/config` file

```
git remote rm “alias or origin”
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use following shell command tools to delete remote repository on github
https://github.com/dfyfhqsfly/github-delete-reponsities.git

Comment: adding some clarification instead of just pasting a link would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Adding and Remove your remote repository from git hub:

*git remote add origin https://github.com/saikumarputta/TodoApi.git*

***git remote remove origin***

Answer (score 0):

1.Navigate to Your Repository

2.click on Settings (under deleted repository)

3.scroll down to the end of the page, got to "**Danger zone**" Section

4.click on **DELETE THIS REPOSITORY**

5.Re-enter the repository name for confirmation.

6.delete