# Can not delete an GitHub repository

Tags: github, repository

I have a git hub repository called "Name" (Without the quote). When I try to delete it:

```
git remote remove Name
```

It returns me this:

```
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.Name'
```

I even check the GitHub website to make sure it exists. It sure does, I don't know why I can't delete this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A git remote is essentially a pointer to another repository.  Removing the remote removes the pointer but does not delete the remote repository.

The git command line tool does not have the ability to delete github repositories.  If you would like to do that you will have to delete it through the github web UI.  See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/) for step by step instructions on how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can delete a github repository using git CLI. In github web interface go to repository settings, there you should find "delete this repository" option under danger zone section, use that option to delete the repository permanently.