# How to delete a repository in github web ui or in git bash?

Tags: git, github

How can I remove one of my repository (public) with github web ui?

Or from the gitbash command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not delete an GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973877/can-not-delete-an-github-repository)

Comment: or [How to delete remote repository on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914342/how-to-delete-remote-repository-on-github)

Answer (score -1):

You can't delete the repo from Github from the command line, but you can remove the repo locally.

`rm -r .git`

Or on Windows
`del -r .git`

Comment: I meant removing the remote repo not the local one.