# How can i remove projects tab

Tags: github

Is it possible to remove the `Projects` tab like I can remove the issue tab? Because we don't really use the `Projects` tab , nor the issue tab.

[image]

Comment: While that is an interesting question and one that I would like to see answered, it doesn't really seem to fit SO since it's about a website, not code.  Github has a [contact page](https://github.com/contact), if you can't find the answer in their [help center](https://help.github.com).  I hesitate to suggest another SE site without experience there, but it *may* be on topic at [webapps.se].

Comment: @zondo , I would tend to Say this is a perfectly askable question for Stackoverflow , and I actually got the answer now to my question. SO Is a place to ask questions that fit the programming criteria and tag criteria. And isn't low-rated questions like Homework questions for instance. Maybe on-topic for Web Applications? That is wrong, web-application is a pretty broad subject, and this question will most definitely get closed as not-relevant or some other issue like that. This specifically relates to github.com , so i think the GitHub tag perfectly fits this question. Cheers, Amanuel.

Comment: But SO is for questions about *code*.  This is not about code; it is about how to control the layout of a website.  Yes, Github hosts code, but that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @zondo there are many questions that isnt directly related to `code` such as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914342/how-to-delete-remote-repository-on-github

Comment: If all things that have been done were okay to do, ... this world would be a terrible place.  Don't show me examples; show me rules that indicate this is an on-topic question.

Comment: This may be more on-topic at the SuperUser SE

Comment: @zondo: This is probably _just_ okay given that it is a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers;" (from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @zondo and your stating the world isnt a terrible place? I show you proof that indicate this question is on-topic. Now im going to cut off this discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [**this**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/309) GitHub issue post it doesn't seem that it is possible to remove the projects tab just like the pull requests tab. Github should make a setting where you can definitely remove this tab, as many repositories aren't using this new feature Github got going on. I'm going to contact GitHub contact page shortly to get ahold of this issue.

## As of 10/28/2016

They said this will be considered as one of the top priorty for Github Developers as said in thier statement:

> Hi!
>
> > I have a question on how to delete the projects tab from your github repository. Is this possible? Can you guys implement this any time soon? I already have asked a question here about it : [How can i remove projects tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296580/how-can-i-remove-projects-tab) , and there is also a github issue about it. If you can inform me more that will be helpfull :-)
>
> This is not possible currently. Thanks for the suggestion though! I have added it to our list for our team to consider.
>
> Thanks,
> GitHub Staff

Sadly , as of right now its not possible to delete the project tab :( .

Comment: How does that sound like it's a "top priority"? That doesn't event sound like it's any sort of priority.

Comment: @Naatan I mean.  It's getting considered :P

Answer (score 2):

Note: since March 24th, 2017, this seems possible.
See "[**Disabling projects**](https://github.com/blog/2339-disabling-projects)" from [**Ayman Nadeem** (`aymannadeem`)](https://github.com/aymannadeem):

> Users with admin privileges on a repository can disable Projects by navigating to that repository's settings and unchecking the "`Projects`" box.
>
> Similarly, organization owners can disable Projects by navigating to an organization's settings and clicking "Projects" in the sidebar.
>   On this page, unchecking the "Enable Projects for the organization" box will disable organization-wide Projects, and unchecking the "Enable Projects for all repositories" box will disable Projects for all repositories in the organization.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/98681/24307394/3c947f8a-1081-11e7-8fab-6106428215f2.png]

> Disabling Projects:
>
> - hides the Projects tab from the repository and organization navigation,
> - removes Projects from Issue and Pull Request sidebars, and
> - hides Project-related events from Issue timelines.
>
> Disabled Projects are also inaccessible via API requests.