# Deleting repo on Github - 404

Tags: github

I have tried following

[this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914342/how-to-delete-remote-repository-on-github)

EDIT: The issue is that I do not have the "Settings" tab!

using the instructions in
[GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/) to get to the settings page.

I just get a 404 for the page.

Is it because my repo is public? If so, how do I delete a public repo?

Comment: To the downvoter - The issue is that I do not have the "Settings" tab, if your concern was thinking I didn't read the existing help on this topic. I apologise that I did not think to mention the lack of this tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution obtained using their site (not the shell).

If you want to delete a public repo from their site, you must first click on the name of the repo in your profile main page.
After that, you'll see a bar with several tabs in the top of your window ('Code, 'Issues', 'Pull request' and 'Settings' are just some of the tabs).

Click on 'Settings', as pointed out in the answer you've already seen, scroll down until you find the 'Danger zone', then 'Delete this repository'.

Are you sure you have permissions to delete that repository? Obviously you can delete only repositories that you own (either public or private).

Hope this helps

**Edit**

If the issue is that you don't have the 'Settings' tab, you can reach repository settings remembering that url has the form https://github.com/username/repo_name/settings .

Comment: The issue is that I do not have the "Settings" tab!

Comment: Did you try to insert manually the url? I noticed that the settings for all my repo are reacheable via https://github.com/username/repo_name/settings . Do you obtain a 404 page not found even substituting by hand in the line above?

Comment: I'm glad that it works ;) now I'll edit my answer with the tips contained in my comment!